# Unable to import read_npz module in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am unable to even find any documentation about the read_npz module.
There is an import statement in the code that I am trying to run. The line is:

`from read_npz import npz2dict`

Can anyone help me to get this module working? This is for converting some numpy array to a dictionary (something of that sort). I am new to this. Any help would be great.

Comment: *"Can anyone help me to get this module working?"*  You haven't given any information about what goes wrong.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If you got an error,  it is helpful to include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: From did you install this module? `numpy` creates and loads `npz` format files, but doesn't have a submodule of that name.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The major issue I am facing is that I am unable to find the documentation. So I was wondering if any of you were familiar with this module. Also about how to install this module.

Comment: @hpaulj I found this in a code from a research article, which I have to reproduce, but I am unable to install this module. Don't even know where to search for this.

Comment: With regular numpy, `data = np.load('afile.npz')` returns a `dict` like object that is used to load the actual arrays, e.g. `arr = data['x']`.  So I can imagine a (researcher's) local module that has a `npz2dict` function that does just that.  How that function is used later in the code may give hints about what it does.   It's not a public available module that I'm aware of, though I haven't searched exhaustively.

Comment: @hpaulj probably its a local module, I am also unable to find it. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this library but if you want to convert your numpy array into a dictionary you can use this :

```
import numpy as np
  
array = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
                  ['d', 'e', 'f'],
                  ['g', 'h', 'i']])

dc = dict(enumerate(array.flatten(), 1))
print(dc)
```

Output :

```
{1: ‘a’, 2: ‘b’, 3: ‘c’, 4: ‘d’, 5: ‘e’, 6: ‘f’, 7: ‘g’, 8: ‘h’, 9: ‘i’}
```

For more details checkout [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-numpy-array-to-dictionary-in-python/) ! Good luck

Comment: Thankyou, but wanted to know if someone could help me install this module.